# SSRS Sharepoint List Query Designer Selecting the View

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I have a website with sharepoint 2010 site i'm pulling data from into a report for SSRS reporting services. On the website, there's an area where we select to change views such as "All Items" or "2013" or "2014".

By default when I run the query designer on SSRS, it pull data from 2014. I would like to know how to edit it such that I can change the view to All Items instead of "2014" where I can pull from that view instead. All items would include everything while 2013 and 2014 would be a smaller set.

Is this possible? I went searching for answers but didn't know what key words to search up and mainly came across links teaching how to use a sharepoint site as a datasource. I have below an example of what i'm trying to do.

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ListName>MyList</ListName>
 <ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="ID" />
</ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SSRS Builder, you can create a Dataset there. Click the Query Designer button and add the fields that you want that is included in a specific view in your SP site.

The code that you've shown will be automatically created once you selected the columns that you wanted to show on a specific view